# Printing Angular2 page only outputs current page

Tags: html, css, angular, media-queries

Our Angular2 application should allow user to print out mutipage report on printer. We generated report html page using **@media print** css. Report displayed fine in the browser (we use Chrome) but when we try to print it out (Ctrl+P) only current page is printed, not the whole report. What might be a problem?